# SOSL not able to fetch records when called from Apex, even though database having matching records

Tags: apex, sosl, dynamic-sosl

I have been facing a unique kind of issue since the last 2 days, I am using SOSL Query in my Apex. It is working on a partial basis, i.e, returning records perfectly in some cases, while not returning any records in other cases.However, the database has matching records based on the criteria, and the SOSL is working fine from the Developer Console.

Can anyone pls suggest any workaround?

I have created a debug log for the query, while running the same on the developer console, it always returns the records.

```
 String searchQuery = 'FIND {* OR *} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ';
        System.debug('>>>>>>>searchQuery from RelatedListMapping>>>'+searchQuery);
        String searchTerm = '';
        Map<String, LC_Setup_Map_Related_List__c> mapChildNameToRelatedListMapping = new Map<String, LC_Setup_Map_Related_List__c>();
        for(LC_Setup_Map_Related_List__c objLCSetup : LC_Setup_Map_Related_List__c.getAll().Values()){
            if(objLCSetup.Parent_Field_On_Child__c != null && objLCSetup.Parent_Field_On_Child__c != '--None--'){
                if(objLCSetup.Parent_Field_On_Child__c != objLCSetup.Lead_Field_on_Child__c){
                    searchTerm += objLCSetup.Child_Object__c + '(Id,' + objLCSetup.Parent_Field_On_Child__c + ',' + objLCSetup.Lead_Field_on_Child__c + ' where ' + searchQueryFilter(setLeadId,objLCSetup.Lead_Field_on_Child__c) + '),';
                    //searchTerm += objLCSetup.Child_Object__c + '(Id,' + objLCSetup.Parent_Field_On_Child__c + ',' + objLCSetup.Lead_Field_on_Child__c + ' where ' + objLCSetup.Lead_Field_on_Child__c + ' =:strLeadId),';
                }
                else
                    searchTerm += objLCSetup.Child_Object__c + '(Id,' + objLCSetup.Parent_Field_On_Child__c + ' where ' + objLCSetup.Lead_Field_on_Child__c + ' =:strLeadId),';
            }
            mapChildNameToRelatedListMapping.put(objLCSetup.Child_Object__c, objLCSetup);
        }
        if(searchTerm != ''){
            searchQuery = searchQuery + searchTerm;
            searchQuery = searchQuery.subStringBeforeLast(',');
            System.debug('>>>>searchQuery>>>>>>'+searchQuery);
            List<List<SObject>> searchList = search.query(searchquery);
            System.debug('>>>>searchList>>>>>>'+searchList);
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of your query. Also are you the running user in both developer console and UI? It could be an access restriction.

Comment: Do you have a conditional/order by clause in SOSL?

Comment: Share some code, It will be help to identify and also try Query in workbench also.

Comment: But this issue is coming in the ratio of 1:10, my code is working fine except for a few times

Comment: I have created a debug log for the query while running the same on the developer console, it always returns the records.

Comment: Quite surprisingly, when I run that piece of code once again, it is returning rows.

Comment: Your bounty reason isn't very compelling...it should be concise like a title, definitely shouldn't contain any code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the intention of the SOSL `FIND {* OR *}`? That SearchQuery seems a bit redundant with the multiple asterisks wildcards. "Match zero or more characters **OR** match zero of more characters"?

I suspect this is causing problems for the ["relevancy AI"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/11067/102) that determines how to satisfy the search with the available indexes.

There may be other factors at play, such as the indexes being rebuilt or user permissions. See [SOSL Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_limits.htm).

If you want to find a more definitive set of results for records related to the Lead consider using several SOQL queries.